# Screening hidden columns of pd.describe() lists

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to have look quick look on distribution of my variables. I employed pd.describe method for this job. However as I have 51 different variables, I am unable to screen all of the columns in the output. Is there a option that forces stats of remaining variables to be screened.

I don't want to view all variables separately one by one.

```py
print(dfts.describe())
        LookupWeekId  WeekdayNumber  ...  max_sicaklik    num_store
count    2033.000000    2033.000000  ...   2027.000000  2033.000000
mean   201656.264634       3.998032  ...     21.169117  1468.741269
std       160.900431       2.000245  ...      9.998129   362.287586
min    201401.000000       1.000000  ...     -0.862828   775.000000
25%    201521.000000       2.000000  ...     12.924433  1170.000000
50%    201641.000000       4.000000  ...     21.350617  1441.000000
75%    201810.000000       6.000000  ...     28.941140  1784.000000
max    201935.000000       7.000000  ...    104.969699  2131.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

`describe()` actually returns a dataframe.  The truncation you are seeing is from Pandas builtin `str` method.  You can do...

```
print(df.describe().to_string(max_cols=df.shape[1]))
```